# How to configure roles with Apache Shiro 1.2-SNAPSHOT and Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, shiro

I'm playing around with Shiro and would like to configure roles via the ShiroWebModule.

```
addFilterChain("/**", AUTHC);
```

this works, my loginpage is shown and I can login.

But

```
addFilterChain("/test/**", AUTHC, config(ROLES, "test")); //that does not seem to be the right way
```

does not. I can access /guest/** and /test/** as guest.

My Module:

```
public class HelloMavenShiroModule extends ShiroWebModule {
    HelloMavenShiroModule(ServletContext sc) {
        super(sc);
    }

    protected void configureShiroWeb() {
        try {
            bindRealm().toConstructor(IniRealm.class.getConstructor(Ini.class));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Code Problem.", e);
        }


        addFilterChain("/**", AUTHC);
        addFilterChain("/guest/**", AUTHC, config(ROLES, "guest"));
        addFilterChain("/test/**", AUTHC, config(ROLES, "[test]"));

        //addFilterChain("/**", AUTHC);
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.loginUrl")).to("/account/login.jsp");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.globalSessionTimeout")).to(30000L);
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.usernameParam")).to("user");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.passwordParam")).to("pass");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.rememberMeParam")).to("remember");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.successUrl")).to("/index.html");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.failureKeyAttribute")).to("helloMavenLoginFailure");
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.unauthorizedUrl")).to("/account/denied.jsp");

        bind(AuthenticationFilter.class).to(VerboseFormAuthenticationFilter.class);
        bind(CredentialsMatcher.class).to(HashedCredentialsMatcher.class);
        bind(HashedCredentialsMatcher.class);
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.hashAlgorithmName")).to(Sha256Hash.ALGORITHM_NAME);
    }

    @Provides
    Ini loadShiroIni() {
        return Ini.fromResourcePath("classpath:shiro.ini");
    }
}
```

The shiro.ini:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Users and their (optional) assigned roles
# username = password, role1, role2, ..., roleN
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[users]
root = 2bb80d537b1da3e38bd30361aa855686bde0eacd7162fef6a25fe97bf527a25b, admin
guest = 84983c60f7daadc1cb8698621f802c0d9f9a3c3c295c810748fb048115c186ec, guest

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Roles with assigned permissions
# roleName = perm1, perm2, ..., permN
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[roles]
admin = *
```

I know it's not released yet, but maybe it's possible already and I just cannot find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found out myself after cleaning up everything and trying again it turns out that:

```
addFilterChain("/test/**", AUTHC, config(ROLES, "test"));
```

was already the right way to do it. I don't know what caused the problem, but now only users with the "test" role are allowed to access resources under /test/ ! Thats exactly what I wanted.

I'm happy now! :)